# What the difference between $A/m$ and $A_0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

$A$ is a integral domain.

$m$ is a maximal ideal .

$A_0$ is the localization of $A$ by $A-0$.(Field of fractions)

$A/m$ is the quotient at $m$.

What the difference between $A/m$ and $A_0$?

Comment: Do you mean $A/m$ as a quotient or as localization at $m$?

Comment: OP: Did you try reading some definitions...?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff of course yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example that will hopefully illustrate the difference. Let $A=\mathbb Z$ and $m=(5)$. $A_0=\mathbb Q$, and $A/m=\mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z$, the integers modulo 5.

Comment: I get it,although they both remove some elements we don't need,but localization make the ring bigger.

Comment: Note that localization (of integral domains) adds elements but doesn't actually remove any. Taking quotients doesn't really remove elements either so much as it identifies them with each other. That is, any two elements of $\mathbb Z$ whose difference is a multiple of $5$ are considered the same element $\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z$. But yes, one tends to think of localizations as enlarging the ring and quotients as contracting it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.They both remove some ideals,not elements.

Comment: Yes. And one can actually think of those ideals as points (the prime ones anyway), and these maps as inclusion of points into the space of prime ideals. But that's another discussion for another post, after you have a lot more commutative algebra under your belt!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case of $A = \mathbb{R}[x]$ and $m=(x^2+1)$. This ideal is maximal since $A/m \cong \mathbb{C}$, while $A_0 = R(x)$, the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{R}$. These are quite distinct. The first is an algebraic extension of the subfield $\mathbb{R}$, while the second is transcendental over $\mathbb{R}$.